# Member object address seems to change when accessed from inherited class

Tags: c++

My code is C++ under Visual Studio 2017.  It worked correctly under VS2013, but after upgrading to VS2017 fails in 32-bit builds (but still works in 64-bit builds).

```
class DerivedFluentUI: public SFLFluentUI
{
    friend CMainFrame;

protected:
    virtual BOOL ImplCaptionBar (CWnd* pParentWnd);
    virtual BOOL ImplRibbonBar (CWnd* pParentWnd, BOOL bCreateAppButton = TRUE, BOOL bCreateBackstageFileTab = FALSE) {return m_wndRibbonBar.Create(pParentWnd);}
};
```

The base class, with much code removed (it's 200 lines long), is:

```
class SFLFluentUI
{
protected:
    virtual BOOL ImplRibbonBar(CWnd* pParentWnd, BOOL bCreateAppButton = TRUE, BOOL bCreateBackstageFileTab = FALSE);
    virtual BOOL ImplCaptionBar(CWnd* pParentWnd);

    SFLRibbonBarEx              m_wndRibbonBar;
    SFLCaptionBarEx             m_wndCaptionBar;
};
```

In DerivedFluentUI::ImplCaptionBar, I call (among other things):

```
m_wndCaptionBar.Create (...)
```

which crashes in 32 bit builds.

When I step into the call to `m_wndCaptionBar.Create` in the debugger, I see that the "this" pointer is not equal to the address of `m_wndCaptionBar` (as viewed from `ImplCaptionBar`).  Last time I checked, they were 0x10d46538 and 0x10d46530, so 8 bytes apart.

If I step into the similar call in `DerivedFluentUI::ImplRibbonBar()` to `m_wndRibbonBar.Create`, the "this" pointer is the same as the address of `m_wndRibbonBar` and it executes successfully.

Stranger still, if I do this in a 64 bit build, then this all works as expected, and the "this" pointer in the call to `m_wndCaptionBar.Create` is equal to `&m_wndCaptionBar` (as viewed from `DerivedFluentUI::ImplCaptionBar`) .

If I call `__super::ImplCaptionBar (...)` (which itself calls `m_wndCaptionBar.Create`) from `DerivedFluentUI::ImplCaptionBar`, then it works correctly, even in 32-bit builds.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something, as I have no idea why this might happen.

Help?!

Edit, per request:
DerivedFluentUI does not have a constructor or destructor, simply overrides those 2 virtual functions.

Constructor for base class, SFLFluentUI:

```
SFLFluentUI::SFLFluentUI(void)
{
    m_pMainPanel                    = NULL;
    m_bLoadedFromResource           = FALSE;
    m_bRibbonInitialized            = FALSE;
    m_bFreqCmdPanels                = FALSE;
    m_bFreqCmdPanelsInitialized     = FALSE;
    m_bIsUsingMainApplicationButton = FALSE;
    m_bIsBackstageFileTabCreated    = FALSE;
    m_pBackstagePropertySheet       = NULL;
    m_bIsBackstageFileWindowVisible = FALSE;
    m_bRibbonMinimizedBeforeBackstage = FALSE;
    m_bHasSysMenu                   = FALSE;

    if (NULL == g_FluentUI)
    {
        g_FluentUI = this;
    }
}
```

**Edit 12/6/2018

This is using the Stingray libraries from RogueWave. I was able to reproduce this in a sample of theirs, which is about as minimal as it gets for a large UI library like we're talking about.  Posting it here doesn't make much sense since you'd need their libraries to run it, but it does mean that I can involve RogueWave technical support.

I'll update the case when they / we figure something out.

**Edit 12/7/2018

The crash seems to be OS dependent.

Windows 7:  Does not crash (tested on 2 machines)

Windows 10: Crashes (tested on 2 machines, 3rd pending)
Windows Server 2012:  Crashes (tested on 1 machine)

I update in case this suggests to anyone some obscure setting or possible chant or incantation I might throw at the issue.  I'm certainly to the point where chanting seems like good science to me (though I must admit that shouting at my machine hasn't fixed things...).

**Edit 4/3/2019

I never figured this out.  Eventually gave up and redesigned things to avoid using DerivedFluentUI, instead modifying the code in the Stingray library to do what I want.  I'm not pleased with this, but...

If anyone ever has insight into this, please update the case.  I'd love to know the problem.

Comment: Where is your code to reproduce the error?

Comment: ... specifically, without a [mcve], it is logically impossible to determine what the problem is. The best you can hope for is random guesses. I suppose that if one's fine with random guesses, this is good enough, but if you hope for a reasonable chance of getting a correct explanation, an [mcve] is required.

Comment: Post the ctor code for both classes. Are SFLRibbonBarEx and SFLCaptionBarEx typedefs?

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference or not; but in your base class you have declared Ribbon then Caption, but in your inherited class you have declared Caption then Ribbon. I don't know if the ordering of these would make such a difference, but try reversing the order of the declarations in your derived class and see if you get the same kind of error.

Comment: I have both Visual Studio 2013 and 17 on my pc. If you are able to post your entire working 2013 solution and source to github I could try it on my machine in 2013 first to see it working then try to port it over to 2017 to see if I could produce similar results.

Comment: @samVarshavchik I'll see if I can reproduce this in a minimal case.

Comment: @tonyJ Neither SFLRibbonBarEx nor SFLCaptionBarEx are typedefs.

Comment: @francisCugler I've tried changing the order, but had same result either way.  I've still got VS2013 on my machine and the code works (and I couldn't share the code anyway).  If I can reproduce it in a small example I'll share that.

Comment: @DougPorter Okay I wasn't sure if the order of the declarations might of made a difference between compiler versions or not. As of the sharing of code that is understandable due to copy right in many cases. But to have an example to play around with on my own machine to compare between versions of Visual Studio would enable me to try and help you to resolve your current issue or problem.

Comment: @tonyj Sorry, forgot the constructor part of your comment.  My derived class does not have a constructor.  I posted the constructor for the base class, SFLFluentUI, in an edit in my post.

Comment: My gut feeling without more code is that there is a problem of the derived class being sliced, or m_wndCaptionBar wasn't constructed properly. Alternatively, it could be in DerivedFluentUI::ImplRibbonBar(), where you memory stomped m_wndCaptionBar. Again without more code, it's really hard to say.